# Golang dynamic variable reference

Tags: variables, dynamic, go, reflection, go-reflect

In Go, I would like to do something like this. I have a big object with many structs (using Google's `protobuf`). here is a contrived example:

```
person.name = "testing"
person.address.street = "123 test st"
person.address.city = "tester"
person.address.zip = 90210
person.billing.address.same = true
```

I would like to be able to dynamically reference things. for example:

```
key := "person.address.zip"
fmt.Println("the value of key: " + key) // would like to get 90210
key := "person.address.city"
fmt.Println("the value of key: " + key) // would like to get "tester"
```

Is this possible in Go? if so, how could I do that? essentially, I'm creating a report which only contains a subset of the object and I want to be able to create a mapping file where the user can map keys/values together and my program will output the value. I have this working in python, but wanted to try using Go :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It provides you package reflect. Disadvantage of reflect is usually big amount of work. On the other hand - without reflect can't be written such perfect packages like html/template or text/template where style of writting is like in interpreted language (like python) although go is compiled.

Comment: and reflect is slow, should be last resort.

Comment: If you really really need something like this, you should use (nested) maps, not hierarchies of struct values.

Comment: Nested maps like `map[string]interface{}` are your friends

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `func (v Value) FieldByName(name string) Value` from `reflect` package:

> FieldByName returns the struct field with the given name. It returns
>   the zero Value if no field was found. It panics if v's Kind is not
>   struct.

Like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    person := Person{}
    person.name = "testing"
    person.address.street = "123 test st"
    person.address.city = "tester"
    person.address.zip = 90210
    person.billing.address.same = true

    v := reflect.ValueOf(person)
    f := v.FieldByName("address")
    key := f.FieldByName("zip")
    fmt.Println(key)                   // 90210
    fmt.Println(f.FieldByName("city")) // tester    
}

type Person struct {
    name    string
    address Address
    billing Billing
}
type Billing struct {
    address Address
}
type Address struct {
    street, city string
    zip          int
    same         bool
}
```

output:

```
90210
tester
```

---

And for your special case, you may use `fmt.Println(field(person, "person.address.zip"))`, like this working sample code (just for demonstration):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"
import "strings"

func field(t interface{}, key string) reflect.Value {
    strs := strings.Split(key, ".")
    v := reflect.ValueOf(t)
    for _, s := range strs[1:] {
        v = v.FieldByName(s)
    }
    return v
}
func main() {
    person := Person{}
    person.name = "testing"
    person.address.street = "123 test st"
    person.address.city = "tester"
    person.address.zip = 90210
    person.billing.address.same = true

    fmt.Println(field(person, "person.address.zip"))  //90210
    fmt.Println(field(person, "person.address.city")) //tester
}

type Person struct {
    name    string
    address Address
    billing Billing
}
type Billing struct {
    address Address
}
type Address struct {
    street, city string
    zip          int
    same         bool
}
```

output:

```
90210
tester
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with *protobuf*'s internals or if it provides any means to do that.

But, *(1)* if you like to read the value in the way you described - by chaining fields dynamically and *(2)* you want to read it more than one time; I would just serialize it into *json* and use [this](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) package. It's very fast and gives you (almost) the same semantic you desire:

```
// assuming your object got marshaled to this for example
json := `{"name":{"first":"Janet","last":"Prichard"},"age":47}`
value := gjson.Get(json, "name.last")
println(value.String())
```